# Как передать данные из кнопки в nib/xib файла в TableView swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, xib

Как в `TableView` в нажатой ячейке в `resulLabel` (результат сложения двух чисел) назначить выбранный ответ из клавиатуры `Nib/Xib` файла

```
class ResultViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, KeyboardDelegate {

var keyboardView = Keyboard()

func keyWasTapped(character: String) {

    //Тут получаю цифру нажатой кнопки
    print("character \(character)")
    pressedResult = character
}

//Тут показываю View из Nib файла
func keyboardWillShow() {
    keyboardView.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 600, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 600)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.keyboardView.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 345, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 600)
    }, completion: nil)

    for i in self.keyboardView.buttons {
        i.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("keyWasTapped")), for: .touchUpInside)
        titleArray += [i.currentTitle!]
    }

    self.view.addSubview(keyboardView)
    isKeyboardEnable = true
}

func keyboardWillHide() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.keyboardView.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 600, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 600)
    }, completion: { finished in self.keyboardView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.isKeyboardEnable = false
    })
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.alpha = 0.1

    cell.firstNumLabel.text = String(oneArray[indexPath.row])
    cell.secondNumLabel.text = String(twoArray[indexPath.row])

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    return cell
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if isKeyboardEnable == false {

        let result = (resultArray[indexPath.row])

        var temp = [Int]()
        temp += [result]
        for _ in 0...10 {
            let random = (Int(arc4random_uniform(82)))
            temp.insert(random, at: 1)
        }

        temp.shuffle()

        for _ in keyboardView.buttons {
            for i in 0 ..< temp.count {
                keyboardView.buttons[i].setTitle(String(temp[i]), for: .normal)
            }
        }

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "keyboardWillShow"), object: nil)

    } else {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "keyboardWillHide"), object: nil)
    }
}
```

Для наглядности

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]